# Prisma How to automatically update "updatedAt" field of parent element when a child element is created or updated?

Tags: node.js, server, backend, prisma

Let's say I have this schema:

```
model User {
   id String @id @default(cuid())
   name String
   email String
   profile Profile?
   createdAt DateTime @default(now())
   updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Profile {
   id Int @id @default(autoicrement())
   bio String?
   avatar String?
   user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
   userId String @unique
}
```

Now what I want to archive is, if a user's profile is updated, for example, a `bio` field is updated, I want the `updatedAt` field on `User` model to automatically reflect that and get updated too to the current timestamp.

Any guide, hint or suggestion will be much appreciated!!

Comment: updatedAt is metadata for the User model. If you need to keep track of when the Profile is updated, you should put updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt on the profile itself. Updating the timestamp on parent model will just confuse developer debugging it in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make some wrapper function I think, for example:

```
const updateUserProfile = (id, data) => {
  return prisma.profile.update({
    where: {
      id
    },
    data: {
      ...data,
      user: {
        update: {
          updatedAt: new Date()
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi hi, thanks for this.  it looks to me like this will use the timestamp based on whatever is executing the prisma client, not on the server time, and is prone to causing bugs.

Comment: @fotoflo it will be executed on the server and it will use your server time of course, what bugs it can cause?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, @Danila, it will be executed on the NodeJS (application) server, aka the Prisma client, not the MySQL or Postgres (database) server.   

Database servers have a now() function. You may run multiple application servers around the globe with different server times, but the database server's time should be the source of truth in the database.  If it's not and you query based on time stamp -- you can see where this is going - you'll be returning times from different clocks - some of which may be set to the future or distant past.

Comment: thanks @Danila, sorry to say you are totally incorrect.  Also rude, but hey it's the internet. Again, new Date() executes in the javascript runtime environment, while select now(); executes in the mysql runtime environment.  I'll write the answer when i get.

Comment: @fotoflo It literally does not matter because date will be store in UTC anyway, so if you have 1 server in USA and 1 in Japan you can still do that, *unless* you server time is incorrect for some reason. If you have correct local server time set then it's all good.

Comment: The solution above is probably fine for a hobby project/small scale.

But to illustrate the issue @fotoflo was saying: imagine you have 3 servers running the same application (e.g. NodeJS) behind a load balancer. All 3 servers will have slightly different time. Let's say:
<Server 1: Time: -1>
 <Server 2: Time: 0>
 <Server 3: Time: +1> 
Now let's say Server 3 saves a record. `updatedAt` is +1. Now Server 1 reads `where updatedAt < ..` but the record was saved in the DB according to Server 3's time. There are other examples where this is problematic.

Comment: @EamonnGahan please don't try to make a completely different argument now and turn discussion upside down, @fotoflo was saying `servers around the globe with different server times`, not +-1 second issue. If you server time is incorrect then you are up for other issues as well, you can't use any date related business logic at all. Also this discussion is 100% unrelated to prisma and original question, if you have different/better answer to the question - just post it.

Comment: no i was talking generally we want to use the database server's now() function instead of the javascript runtime's time. @EamonnGahan has it right.