# Prisma updateAt column with Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, prisma

Is there a way for `updatedAt` column to insert current date on change. Right now in schema.prisma I am using

```
updatedAt DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt
```

But it does not work.

I suppose a trigger can be created directly inside the database. But is there a way to do that with schema.prisma?

Comment: If it is a SQL DB and you want it updated on INSERT you can have the column DEFAULT to the current date.   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prisma How to automatically update "updatedAt" field of parent element when a child element is created or updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806367/prisma-how-to-automatically-update-updatedat-field-of-parent-element-when-a-ch)